# Is Strunk and White's "The Elements" full of "stupid grammar advice?"

Tags: style

In a [previous question](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/1478/strunk-and-white-vs-style-the-basics-of-clarity-and-grace-by-williams-and-colo) I asked about *The Elements*, RegDwight posted a comment containing a link to this article by Geoffrey K. Pullum:

[50 Years of Stupid Grammar Advice](http://chronicle.com/article/50-Years-of-Stupid-Grammar/25497).

There is also a lengthier critique [here.](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/~gpullum/ETfinalProof.pdf)

The article seemed convincing and I am avoiding *The Elements* as a result. However, I'm certainly not a grammar expert and am curious to see if others agree or disagree with Pullum's article.

If you post an answer, I ask that you actually read the article first and give specifics as to why you agree or disagree.  Simple "yes" or "no" answers can be indicated by up or down voting other responses.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2909/what-is-wrong-in-strunk-whites-elements-of-style

Comment: I don't think anyone can really answer it any better than those on English.SE already have.

Comment: @John Smithers Thanks for the link.  I probably should have made a more thorough search of the other Stack Exchange sites before posting this question.  Would it be more appropriate to delete the question or post an answer linking to the English.SE thread?

Comment: @Brandon: I already voted to close your question. You can do the same. That's the way to go.

Comment: @John Smithers I would vote to close... However, I'm a new user and apparently it requires 250 reputation to do that even though it's my own question.

Comment: @Brandon: I informed the moderators.